Very basic query about Quaternions: How do I assign a variable to a quaternion?
I just started looking at the Quaternions package. I immediately hit a problem trying to assign a quaternion to a variable. Can somebody tell me what I'm missing in my understanding?
Below are the few lines of code that I tried, along with the Mathematica output. I seem to have successfully set q1 to be a quaternion. Its head is 'Quaternion' but QuaternionQ returns false and FromQuaternion fails.
Your assistance will be appreciated.
Needs["Quaternions`"]
q1 = Quaternion[a , b , c, d ]
Print["FullForm of q1: ", q1 // FullForm];
Print["Head of q1: ", Head @ q1];
Print["Is q1 a quaternion? ", QuaternionQ[q1]];
Print["Trying FromQuaternion: ", FromQuaternion[q1]]

Quaternion[a, b, c, d]
FullForm of q1: Quaternion[a,b,c,d]
Head of q1: Quaternion
Is q1 a quaternion? False
Quaternion expected at position 1 in FromQuaternion[]
Trying FromQuaternion: FromQuaternion[Quaternion[a,b,c,d]]

In the Quaternions package documentation
"all quaternions should be entered using the form Quaternion[a,b,c,d] where a, b, c, and d are real numbers. Only limited support is offered to the symbolic form a+Ib+Jc+Kd." Your code works as expected if you define your quaternion components numerically (e.g. a=b=c=d=1)

You could take a look at my package on Github. It can handle symbolic quaternions.

Thanks.  I'll have a a squiz.
